# HTTP GET doesn't give me full sourcecode (max. size inputstream?)

Tags: java, http, get, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to put a large webpage into a String ([https://hsreplay.net/api/v1/analytics/query/list_deck_inventory/](http://webpage))
I'm using following code:

```
public static String GET(String URL) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect();    
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) result.append(line);
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

This returns me only the 121.223 first charachters of that page, while I really need to get the full page.
When using postman, I get the full page as return.
Is there a maximum amount of charachters a GET can read, or a inputstream/bufferedreader can have?
Is there a way to get all the text into my result string?

Comment: when you use BufferedReader.readLine() you get only the line without the trailing newline. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: If I save that page locally I get only 121 023 bytes. So that seems to be the full page. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: How does this fix my problem? Since it reads the line and then stops; it means that the end of my inputstream is reached thus not everything I want is in the inputstream. I think that's the problem.

Comment: If you need the newlines simply add `result.append("\n");` after you append the line.